# Can't typeset cedilla

Tags: accents, bibitem

I'm trying to typeset a lower-case letter "a" with a cedilla:

`\c{a}`

but this just produces an italic lower-case "c" immediately followed by a regular lower-case "a". Other accent escape codes work fine, e.g.

`\"{o}`

produces a lower-case "o" with an umlaut.

This is in a \bibitem at the end of my document. I am not using bibtex, just a vanilla

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{foo} bar
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: My crystal ball suggests me that somebody redefined `\c`. If you didn't do it yourself, then it's your template doing it. We need more information.

Comment: @egreg got it, the template I'm using had redefined `\c`. Is there a way to mark as solved if the answer is in a comment?

Comment: We don't have these problems when we are using Unicode engines and the letter a̧ directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your template, it's quite likely that it redefines `\c` with something like

```
\def\c{\ensuremath{c}}
```

according to the symptoms you describe. Possibly to use `\c` for denoting the speed of light or something else I cannot imagine.

Remove the rogue redefinition and change template if you can: if it has `\def\c{...}`, then it probably has something even worse.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks! The template I'm using (not of my making) had redefined `\c` as the symbol for a charm quark.

Comment: @RobS Of course they should have chosen `\cq` or other more meaningful command. A colleague of mine used to do `\def\c{\gamma}` (he knew Greek) and once he wrote me asking why the name of his Turkish coauthor (starting with Ş) gave weird errors. `;-)`

Answer (score -1):

I found just similar to your (a lower-case letter "a" with a cedilla) but with very different name, the (ogonek) from
[a table at wikibook page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters)
and it seems already available in TeX with the script \k{a} as simple as the cedilla \c{c}. I guess it would suitable for your use.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! But sorry, I would describe this as tinkering with the symptoms rather than fixing the cause of the problem.